# Flutter camera options

Tags: flutter, camera, android-camera

What I need is access to the camera and the normal features the camera would provide (e.g. changing the ISO value manually).
After doing some research I found two options to take a photo from within Flutter:

- [Image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker): Here the built-in camera app will be used, but is heavily restricted. There are hardly any settings which can be changed and not a lot of freedom to make a photo with specific settings.
- [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera): If I understood correctly, this is basically an access to the camera lens itself, so there is no camera software involved and I would need to implement all the basic features a camera provides, by myself.

My aim is to be able to take a photo with all (or at least most) of the common functionality a camera provides included. Is there another plugin I did not find by now or some way the remove the restrictions by the Image Picker?